# Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of order n so that $AB = BA$. Prove $\mathrm{rank}(A+B) \leq \mathrm{rank}(A) + \rm{rank}(B) - \mathrm{rank}(AB)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

For $AB=BA$ to hold, that would mean, $A$ is a diagonal or identity matrix. I tried substituting real matrices in and realized that $\mathrm{rank}(AB) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$, so that means $\mathrm{rank}(A+B) \leq \mathrm{rank}(B)$.

But how do I formalize this as a proof? Am I on the right track?

and also why is it that it is $\mathrm{rank}(A+B) \leq \mathrm{rank}k(B)$ and not just $\mathrm{rank}(A+B) =\mathrm{rank}(B)$?

Appreciate your help and thanks!

Comment: There are many more pairs of matrices where $AB=BA$.  For example, when $A$ is a power of $B$.

Comment: meaning to say A=B?

Comment: @matthew.j There are many more examples of $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=BA$. Neither of them have to be diagonal or identity matrices.

Comment: Consider the following example, let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.  These do not satisfy that $rank(A+B)\leq rank (B)$.

Comment: Also, the rank of $AB$ is less than or equal to the rank of $A$.

Comment: oh yea... thanks for pointing that out. hmm.. any advice how to tackle this?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1**: Show that the column space $C(A+B)$ of $A+B$ is contained in $C(A) + C(B)$. Deduce that the rank of $A+B$ (dimension of its column space) is lesser or equal than $\dim(C(A) + C(B)) = \dim C(A) + \dim C(B) - \dim(C(A) \cap C(B))$.

**Hint 2**: Argue that $C(AB) \subseteq C(A)$ and similarly $C(BA) \subseteq C(B)$. Then use the fact that $A,B$ commute to conclude that $\dim(C(A) \cap C(B)) \geq \dim C(AB)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are many statements that are incorrect in the original post.

(1) There are many pairs of matrices $A$ and $B$ so that $AB=BA$.  For example, consider the case where $A=B^k$ for some $k$.  Then $AB=B^{k+1}=BA$.

(2) The statement that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ is false.  Consider, for example, the case where $B$ is the zero matrix.  In general, it is true that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leq\operatorname{rank}(A)$.

(3) The statement that $\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\leq\operatorname{rank}(B)$ is false.  Consider, for example, where $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.  Then $\operatorname{rank}(A+B)=2$ but $\operatorname{rank}(B)=1$.

Comment: may I also ask. how can I master linear algebra? I find that it's different from calculus where practice helps a lot.

Comment: Practice still helps a lot, but you have to also practice theoretical questions (and keep track of all your theorems).

Comment: oh ok. thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a proof by using **partitioned matrices**.

> From $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
> I&I\\
> O&I
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> A&\\
> &B
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> I&-B\\
> I&A
> \end{bmatrix}
> =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> A+B&-AB+BA\\
> B&BA
> \end{bmatrix}
> =\begin{bmatrix}
> A+B&O\\
> B&AB
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> we know
> $$
> r(A)+r(B)\geq r(LHS)=r(RHS) \geq r(A+B)+r(AB)
> $$
> in which $r(\cdot)$ represents rank of matrix.

I think it's actually an elegant proof but I have no idea or reasonable explanation about where the inspiration comes from. Up to now, I think the proof of using theory of linear space is more acceptable.

Comment: A posted "answer" is not the place to ask questions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I fixed that and disagree with the Community Bot.

Comment: @KurtG. Good for you, but this is really something the OP should fix, in order to learn the standards of the place.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks! I’m not familiar with the rule here but I will comply with this standard later.

Comment: I think maybe it's right to ask here. 
**How to understand this proof better?**

Comment: @Vanellope . Are you asking where the inspiration might come from or do you have technical difficulties understanding that proof ? In the first case you may want to give the reference where you found it.

Comment: @Vanellope No, this is not the right place. If you have a mathematical question, post it as a question (with appropriate context). Don't ask it in an answer, don't ask it buried in the comments.

Comment: @KurtG. The first case! ! I’m sad that I found this problem and its proof from a reference book for advanced algebra course, where there is nothing else besides I posted above.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks! I understand! Please just let my fault go this time.

Comment: @Vanellope If that proof is in a known book it might indeed be worth to ask about where the inspiration might have come from in a *separate* question where you can still refer to this question in a link. In so far I agree with Arturo Magidin. Most likely though it would not be the first proof that comes to us stripped from its inspiration. Elegant is it by all means. That's what counts.